# use custom labels in stat_bin ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code creates a histogram and puts count label over each bar.

```
breaks=seq(0,100,by=10)
ggplot(df, aes(x=spread,y=..count../sum(..count..))) +
  stat_bin(breaks=breaks,fill='red',colour='black')+
 stat_bin(breaks=breaks,geom='text',aes(label=..count..),vjust=-1.5,pad=FALSE)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks)
```

There are 10 bins and I would like to put my own (not count) label over each bar 
, e.g.

```
my_label=log(1:10) #Could be anything here
ggplot(df, aes(x=spread,y=..count../sum(..count..))) + 
  stat_bin(breaks=breaks,fill='red',colour='black')+
  stat_bin(breaks=breaks,geom='text',aes(label=my_label),vjust=-1.5,pad=FALSE)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks)
```

If I do it this way I get an error:
`Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (847): label, x`

Is there a SIMPLE way to do that? I understand that some people suggest using dplyr package and modifying the data frame (df), creating essentially a data frame of the statistics of the original data frame. Is there anything more simple than that? After all, we use histogram plotting to avoid performing binning and statistics ourselves.

Comment: Have you looked at `?geom_histogram`

Comment: con you provide some sample data, e.g. using `dput(df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
breaks <- seq(0,100,by=10)
df <- data.frame(spread = rnorm(1000,50,10))
my_label <- letters[1:10] #Could be anything here
ggplot(df, aes(x=spread,y=..count../sum(..count..))) + 
  stat_bin(breaks=breaks,fill='red',colour='black')+
  stat_bin(breaks=breaks,geom='text',label=my_label,vjust=-1.5,pad=FALSE)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks)
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Here is a solution for a further question asked by @user5768239: 
*Is there a way to remove labels where ..count..==0?*

```
breaks <- seq(0,100,by=10)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(spread = rnorm(1000,40,8))
spread_cat <- cut(df$spread, breaks=breaks)
tbl <- table(spread_cat)
my_label <- letters[1:10] #Could be anything here
my_label[tbl==0] <- ""
ggplot(df, aes(x=spread,y=..count../sum(..count..))) + 
  stat_bin(breaks=breaks,fill='red',colour='black')+
  stat_bin(breaks=breaks,geom='text',label=my_label,vjust=-1.5,pad=FALSE)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to remove labels 'a' and 'j' where ..count..==0? It doesn't look like we can use ..count.. outside of aes().

Comment: Thanks. What if I don't know ahead of time which labels have ..count..==0 and would like to remove those ones?